# Como aplicar regras do jQuery Validate para vários campos de uma vez?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validação, jquery-validate

Tenho um formulário em ASP.NET e estou utilizando o jQuery Validate para aplicar regras de validação nos campos. Todos os meus campos têm uma regra em comum (`required: true`) mas não consegui achar uma forma de aplicar isso a todos de uma vez.

```
$('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            '<%= txtRazaoSocial.UniqueID %>': {
                required: true
            },
            '<%= txtNomeFantasia.UniqueID %>': {
                required: true
            },
            '<%= txtCNPJ.UniqueID %>': {
                required: true,
                cnpj: true
            },
            '<%= txtCEP.UniqueID %>': {
                required: true
            },
            '<%= txtLogradouro.UniqueID %>': {
                required: true
            },
            '<%= txtNumeroLogradouro.UniqueID %>': {
                required: true
            },
            '<%= txtBairro.UniqueID %>': {
                required: true 
[...]
```

É possível solucionar este problema?

EDIT: tentei da forma abaixo também, porém não funcionou.

```
$('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
      required: true,
    },
```

Comment: Adiciona em todos os fields a classe required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você também pode tentar isso

```
//Você coloca todos os campos que tiver, select, textarea etc..
$("#form1 input").each(function () {
  $(this).rules("add", {
    required: true
  });
});
```

Ou adicionar `class="required"` nos campos do seu formulário, como dito nos comentários.

Comment: Considerei esta como resposta correta pois uma das soluções propostas foi somente adicionar a classe 'required' nos campos, o que solucionou meu problema. De qualquer forma, obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Adicione

```
class="required"
```

Nos campos que você quer que se tornem obrigatórios.

E no javascript faça

```
$(function () {
  $.validator.setValidator('idDoSeuForm');
});
```